# read specific line in text and sum the numbers and the following lines

Tags: python, text, sum, line, readline

hi im having trouble with some homework that i got. i have a list of number in a text file written in several lines. my project is asking me to select a specific line and then a number of line after to sum them up. For example from line 4 sum the next 4 line. 
this is the code i have tried for now

```
fichNbr = open("nombres.txt", "r")
ligneDepart = int(input("entrer la ligne de depart: "))
nb_lignes = int(input("entrer le nombre de ligne a lire: "))
somme3 = 0
for line in fichNbr:
    line = fichNbr.readline()
    print(line)
    for i in range(ligneDepart,(ligneDepart + nb_lignes),1):
        n = fichNbr.readline().split()
        for f in n:
                somme3 += int(f)
print(somme3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get what your code is doing wrong (kind of in a hurry so not enough time to analyse sorry) but if you're looking for a code that kind of does what you need (I think) here it is:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
start_line = input("line to start ") - 1
finish_line = input("line to finish ") - 1
soma = 0
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i >= start_line and i <= finish_line:
        soma += int(line)
print soma
```

Just a quick explanation, enumeration is a built-in function that will iterate through the file f and return a tuple containing the line number (starting from zero) and whatever is in the line. All you need to do is check if i is equal or greater than the line you wanna start reading from and also smaller than the line you wanna stop reading at.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you i will tri it out

Answer (score 0):

To do the sum of all lines (including the given line) from the designated line, you line variable needs to subtract 1. If it is exclusive of that line then just use the variable as is. Open the file using with ... as to have it close automatically and choose read ('r') as the mode. Create a variable to store the lines and choose readlines(). This stores each line into its own place in a list.

Create another variable to actually sum the lines. Using a while loop associated to you given start line variable, as long as it is less than the length of your list, iterate through the list adding each line to your sum variable (as shown using nums).

Because of how open() read the lines, it pulls it all as strings with \n at the end. Add strip('\n') to remove the \n and convert it all into an integer. Add 1 to your line variable to properly iterate and end the loop.

```
def example(file_name, line):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        x = f.readlines()
    line = line - 1
    nums = 0
    while line < len(x):
        nums += int(x[line].strip('\n'))
        line += 1
    print(nums)

example("example.txt", 4)
# My example.txt file has a different number on each line in this order: 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 4
```

If you want to do only a certain number of lines following the given line, add this extra number to the function and then add the line variable to this extra variable BEFORE subtracting 1 from the line variable. Instead of going iterating the length of the list, using this modified extra variable as you end.

```
def example(file_name, line, end_line):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        x = f.readlines()
    end_line += line
    line = line - 1
    nums = 0
    while line < end_line:
        nums += int(x[line].strip('\n'))
        line += 1
    print(nums)

example("example.txt", 4, 2)
# My example.txt file has a different number on each line in this order: 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 4
```

Again, if you do not want the given line included, do not subtract 1.

Comment: No problem. Hope it helped. I'm not sure what the issues were with your code, so I cannot comment on it, but you should use "with open("nombres.txt", "r") as fichNbr:" instead of "fichNbr = open("nombres.txt", "r")" because your script never closes the file, but with...as it does.

Comment: If one of these responses answered your question, please remember to mark it as answered.